# MinIO AWS CLI via nginx-ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, minio

Running MinIO (https://docs.min.io/) on kubernetes 1.12. I am unable to run aws cli commands via nginx-ingress. Commands work fine when port-forwarding directly to the kubernetes service.

Tried

```
 proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

and

```
 more_set_input_headers 'Host: minio:9000';
```

nginx rules but with no luck.

Example request:

```
aws s3 ls --endpoint-url https://my-endpoint-url.com --profile=minio
```

**Unable to list bucket content. Instead receive error:**

> An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the ListBuckets
>   operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the
>   signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned about to be an issue w/ a rewrite. (Broke presigned URLs.)

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /mybucket/$1

Removing the rewrite, and modifying the path in the request, fixed the issue.

Comment: can you post your config?